# Delphi 11.1 crash staring Foregound Service

Tags: android, delphi-11-alexandria

I just upgraded from Delhi 11.0 to 11.1, because of issues with Jlocation on Android 12.

Now my App no longer works at all, on ANY version of Android.

It crashes when the App starts the Foreground Service, looks like the 'OnCreate'. It is dead before the first log entry.

The App starts the Service like this:

```
DoLog('Init is starting Service');
        TLocalServiceConnection.StartService('SARTrackService');
```

The Android Log shows this (snipped a big chunk out), I do not understand it, it is not my code:

```
06-30 15:33:26.372: I/info(22110): SARTrack Client: [15:33:26.363] Init is starting Service

06-30 15:33:26.563: W/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): CheckJNI: method to register "dispatchToNative2" not in the given class. This is slow, consider changing your RegisterNatives calls.
06-30 15:33:26.563: E/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): ----- class 'Lcom/embarcadero/services/SARTrackServiceProxyInterface;' cl=0x14040590 -----
06-30 15:33:26.563: E/ack.SARTrackAp(22110):   objectSize=188 (172 from super)
06-30 15:33:26.563: E/ack.SARTrackAp(22110):   access=0x0008.0001
06-30 15:33:26.563: E/ack.SARTrackAp(22110):   super='java.lang.Class<java.lang.Object>' (cl=0x0)
06-30 15:33:26.564: E/ack.SARTrackAp(22110):   interfaces (1):
06-30 15:33:26.564: E/ack.SARTrackAp(22110):      0: java.lang.Class<java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler> (cl=0x0)
06-30 15:33:26.564: E/ack.SARTrackAp(22110):   vtable (4 entries, 11 in super):
06-30 15:33:26.564: E/ack.SARTrackAp(22110):      0: java.lang.Object com.embarcadero.services.SARTrackServiceProxyInterface.CreateProxyClass(java.lang.Class, long)
06-30 15:33:26.564: E/ack.SARTrackAp(22110):      1: void com.embarcadero.services.SARTrackServiceProxyInterface.cleanNative(long)
06-30 15:33:26.564: E/ack.SARTrackAp(22110):      2: java.lang.Object com.embarcadero.services.SARTrackServiceProxyInterface.dispatchToNative(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object[], long)
06-30 15:33:26.564: E/ack.SARTrackAp(22110):      3: java.lang.Object com.embarcadero.services.SARTrackServiceProxyInterface.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.reflect.Method, java.lang.Object[])
06-30 15:33:26.564: E/ack.SARTrackAp(22110):   direct methods (1 entries):
06-30 15:33:26.564: E/ack.SARTrackAp(22110):      0: void com.embarcadero.services.SARTrackServiceProxyInterface.<init>()
06-30 15:33:26.564: E/ack.SARTrackAp(22110):   instance fields (1 entries):
06-30 15:33:26.564: E/ack.SARTrackAp(22110):      0: long com.embarcadero.services.SARTrackServiceProxyInterface.pointer
06-30 15:33:26.564: E/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): Failed to register native method com.embarcadero.services.SARTrackServiceProxyInterface.dispatchToNative2(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; in /data/app/nz.sartrack.SARTrackApp-goI3CrRvcsABMeDExErzog==/base.apk
06-30 15:33:26.959: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): java_vm_ext.cc:542] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI RegisterNatives called with pending exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no static or non-static method "Lcom/embarcadero/services/SARTrackServiceProxyInterface;.dispatchToNative2(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object;"
06-30 15:33:26.959: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at void com.embarcadero.rtl.ProxyService.onCreateNative(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String) (ProxyService.java:-2)
06-30 15:33:26.959: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at void com.embarcadero.rtl.ProxyService.onCreate(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String) (ProxyService.java:51)
06-30 15:33:26.959: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at void com.embarcadero.services.SARTrackService.onCreate() (SARTrackService.java:40)
06-30 15:33:26.960: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(android.app.ActivityThread$CreateServiceData) (ActivityThread.java:3804)
06-30 15:33:26.960: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at void android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$CreateServiceData) (ActivityThread.java:248)
06-30 15:33:26.960: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1846)
06-30 15:33:26.960: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:106)
06-30 15:33:26.960: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:216)
06-30 15:33:26.960: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:7266)
06-30 15:33:26.960: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
06-30 15:33:26.960: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at void com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (RuntimeInit.java:494)
06-30 15:33:26.960: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:975)
06-30 15:33:26.960: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): java_vm_ext.cc:542] 
06-30 15:33:26.960: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): java_vm_ext.cc:542]     in call to RegisterNatives
06-30 15:33:26.960: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): java_vm_ext.cc:542]     from void com.embarcadero.rtl.ProxyService.onCreateNative(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String)
06-30 15:33:26.960: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): java_vm_ext.cc:542] "main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
06-30 15:33:26.960: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): java_vm_ext.cc:542]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x74b70618 self=0xeaccd000
06-30 15:33:26.960: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): java_vm_ext.cc:542]   | sysTid=22110 nice=-10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xef35c4a8
06-30 15:33:26.960: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): java_vm_ext.cc:542]   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=471 stm=55 core=1 HZ=100
06-30 15:33:26.960: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): java_vm_ext.cc:542]   | stack=0xff63f000-0xff641000 stackSize=8MB
06-30 15:33:26.960: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): java_vm_ext.cc:542]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
06-30 15:33:26.960: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #00 pc 002e618f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, int, BacktraceMap*, char const*, art::ArtMethod*, void*, bool)+134)
06-30 15:33:26.960: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #01 pc 00380b6d  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::DumpStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, bool, BacktraceMap*, bool) const+212)
06-30 15:33:26.960: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #02 pc 0037d12b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, bool, BacktraceMap*, bool) const+34)
06-30 15:33:26.960: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #03 pc 00239ce7  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbort(char const*, char const*)+722)
06-30 15:33:26.960: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #04 pc 0023a04f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbortV(char const*, char const*, std::__va_list)+58)
06-30 15:33:26.960: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #05 pc 000c56a7  /system/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::ScopedCheck::AbortF(char const*, ...)+46)
06-30 15:33:26.960: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #06 pc 000c4349  /system/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::ScopedCheck::CheckPossibleHeapValue(art::ScopedObjectAccess&, char, art::(anonymous namespace)::JniValueType)+1080)
06-30 15:33:26.960: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #07 pc 000c382b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::ScopedCheck::Check(art::ScopedObjectAccess&, bool, char const*, art::(anonymous namespace)::JniValueType*)+622)
06-30 15:33:26.960: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #08 pc 000bdf1b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::CheckJNI::RegisterNatives(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, JNINativeMethod const*, int)+530)
06-30 15:33:26.960: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #09 pc 0047a37d  /data/app/nz.sartrack.SARTrackApp-goI3CrRvcsABMeDExErzog==/lib/arm/libSARTrackService.so (???)

[SNIP}

06-30 15:33:26.961: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #98 pc 00071c33  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_JNIEnv::CallStaticVoidMethod(_jclass*, _jmethodID*, ...)+38)
06-30 15:33:26.961: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #99 pc 000740df  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, android::Vector<android::String8> const&, bool)+478)
06-30 15:33:26.961: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #100 pc 00002f35  /system/bin/app_process32 (main+728)
06-30 15:33:26.961: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #101 pc 0008dcdd  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+48)
06-30 15:33:26.961: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #102 pc 00002c1d  /system/bin/app_process32 (_start_main+40)
06-30 15:33:26.961: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #103 pc 00000306  <anonymous:ef359000> (???)
06-30 15:33:26.961: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at com.embarcadero.rtl.ProxyService.onCreateNative(Native method)
06-30 15:33:26.961: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at com.embarcadero.rtl.ProxyService.onCreate(ProxyService.java:51)
06-30 15:33:26.961: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at com.embarcadero.services.SARTrackService.onCreate(SARTrackService.java:40)
06-30 15:33:26.961: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3804)
06-30 15:33:26.961: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:248)
06-30 15:33:26.961: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1846)
06-30 15:33:26.961: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
06-30 15:33:26.961: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
06-30 15:33:26.961: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7266)
06-30 15:33:26.961: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native method)
06-30 15:33:26.961: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
06-30 15:33:26.961: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
06-30 15:33:26.961: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): java_vm_ext.cc:542] 
06-30 15:33:27.201: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): thread.cc:2155] No pending exception expected: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no static or non-static method "Lcom/embarcadero/services/SARTrackServiceProxyInterface;.dispatchToNative2(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object;"
06-30 15:33:27.201: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): thread.cc:2155]   at void com.embarcadero.rtl.ProxyService.onCreateNative(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String) (ProxyService.java:-2)
06-30 15:33:27.201: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): thread.cc:2155]   at void com.embarcadero.rtl.ProxyService.onCreate(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String) (ProxyService.java:51)
06-30 15:33:27.201: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): thread.cc:2155]   at void com.embarcadero.services.SARTrackService.onCreate() (SARTrackService.java:40)
06-30 15:33:27.201: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): thread.cc:2155]   at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(android.app.ActivityThread$CreateServiceData) (ActivityThread.java:3804)
06-30 15:33:27.201: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): thread.cc:2155]   at void android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$CreateServiceData) (ActivityThread.java:248)
06-30 15:33:27.201: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): thread.cc:2155]   at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1846)
06-30 15:33:27.201: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): thread.cc:2155]   at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:106)
06-30 15:33:27.201: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): thread.cc:2155]   at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:216)
06-30 15:33:27.201: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): thread.cc:2155]   at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:7266)
06-30 15:33:27.201: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): thread.cc:2155]   at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
06-30 15:33:27.201: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): thread.cc:2155]   at void com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (RuntimeInit.java:494)
06-30 15:33:27.201: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): thread.cc:2155]   at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:975)
06-30 15:33:27.201: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): thread.cc:2155] 
06-30 15:33:27.591: A/ack.SARTrackAp(22110): runtime.cc:577] Runtime aborting --- recursively, so no thread-specific detail!
```

Help...

Answer (score 0):

okay, another bug in 11.1. The solution found here:

https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/HowTo/tree/main/Solutions/AndroidServiceDelphi111

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, due to low reputation here, I can't mark the previous answer as "ThumbUp", but the answer from "Bart Kindt" just helped me.

> okay, another bug in 11.1. The solution found here:
> https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/HowTo/tree/main/Solutions/AndroidServiceDelphi111

[saved screenshot of the https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/HowTo/tree/main/Solutions/AndroidServiceDelphi111](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYKya.png)

Thank You.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).